# DataTable is not working properly in primefaces 6.0

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

[When I click on any of the input box ( resource, phone and email) for filter it's filter data but format is not coming properly(please click on this link to see the screen shot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXCHY.png)

[It's coming in this format.(please click on this link to see the screen shot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7tKX.png)

```
<p:dataTable id="teamList"  
             var="element" value="#{manager.resourcesTeam}" editable="true"
             style="overflow:scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height:195px"> 
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" />
    <!--  Resource Name -->
    <p:column headerText="#{crud['escalation.matrix.elements.resource']}" 
              filterBy="#{element.name}" 
              filterMatchMode="contains"
              filterStyle="border: 1px solid lightGrey"
              sortBy="#{element.name}"
              style="width:280px; background-image:none;">                      
        <h:outputText id="resourceName" 
                      value="#{nsn:substring(element.name, 35)}"
                      title="#{element.name.length() > 35 ? element.name : ''}"
                      style="#{element.name.length() > 35 ? 'cursor: help;' : ''}" />
       <p:tooltip for="resourceName" 
                   style="z-index:9999 !important;"> 
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:outputText value="#{crud['team.integration.keys']}" style="font-weight:bold" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputText value="#{crud['team.tam.username']}: " style="font-weight:bold"/>
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputText value="#{crud['team.ipm.username']}: " style="font-weight:bold"/>
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputText value="#{crud['team.nols.username']}: " style="font-weight:bold"/>
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
         </p:tooltip> 
    </p:column> 

    <!--  Resource phone number -->
    <p:column headerText="#{crud['escalation.matrix.elements.phone']}"  
              filterBy="#{manager.engineerPhone(element)}" 
              filterStyle="border: 1px solid lightGrey"
              filterMatchMode="contains"
              style="width: 125px; background-image: none; text-align: center;">                        
        <h:outputText value="#{manager.engineerPhone(element) != 0 ? manager.engineerPhone(element) : ''}"/>
    </p:column> 

    <!--  Resource E-mail -->
    <p:column headerText="#{crud['escalation.matrix.elements.useEmail']}" 
              filterBy="#{element.email}" 
              filterMatchMode="contains"
              filterStyle="border: 1px solid lightGrey"
              sortBy="#{element.email}"
              style="width:200px; background-image:none;">                      
        <h:outputText value="#{nsn:substring(element.email, 25)}"
                      title="#{element.email.length() > 25 ? element.email : ''}"
                      style="#{element.email.length() > 25 ? 'cursor: help;' : ''}" />
    </p:column> 

    <!--  Resource Dispatchable -->
    <p:column headerText="#{crud['lov.assignment.dispatch.filter']}" 
              style="width: 15px; text-align: center;" rendered="#{not globalScreen}">                      
        <p:cellEditor>  
            <f:facet name="output">  
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="positive_green_hand_16x16.png" 
                                styleClass="ico" style="padding-left: 2px;" 
                                rendered="#{manager.engineerDispatchable(element)}" />
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="negative_red_hand_16x16.png" 
                                styleClass="ico" style="padding-left: 2px;" 
                                rendered="#{not manager.engineerDispatchable(element)}" />
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{manager.engineerDispatchable(element)}" />
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column> 

    <!-- Options -->
    <p:column headerText="#{crud['escalation.matrix.elements.options']}" 
              style="width: 60px; text-align: center;" rendered="#{not (manager.instance.isGlobalTeam() and manager.managed and manager.teamScreen)}">  
        <h:commandLink id="remove" action="#{manager.removeResource(element)}">
            <h:graphicImage library="images" title="#{actions['remove']}"
                            name="blue_minus_signal_16x16.png" styleClass="ico" />
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":crudForm:teamList :messages" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>   
</p:dataTable>
```

What is the reason behind this, is it related to CSS problem?